# Delphi Tokyo 64-bit flushes denormal numbers to zero?

Tags: delphi, floating-point

During a short look at the source code of system.math, I discovered that
the 64-bit version Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3 flushes denormal IEEE-Doubles to zero, as can be seen from then following program;

```
{$apptype console}
uses
  system.sysutils, system.math;
var
  x: double;
const
  twopm1030 : UInt64 = $0000100000000000; {2^(-1030)}
begin
  x := PDouble(@twopm1030)^;
  writeln(x);
  x := ldexp(1,-515);
  writeln(x*x);
  x := ldexp(1,-1030);
  writeln(x);
end.
```

For 32-bit the output is as expected

```
8.69169475979376E-0311
8.69169475979376E-0311
8.69169475979376E-0311
```

but with 64-bit I get

```
 8.69169475979375E-0311
 0.00000000000000E+0000
 0.00000000000000E+0000
```

So basically Tokyo can handle denormal numbers in 64-bit mode, the constant is written correctly, but from arithmetic operations or even with ldexp a denormal result is flushed to zero.

Can this observation be confirmed on other systems? If yes, where it is documented? (The only info I could find about zero-flushing is, 
that `Denormals become zero when stored in a Real48`).

**Update:** I know that for **both** 32- and 64-bit the single overload is used. For 32-bit the x87 FPU is used and the ASM code is virtually identical for all precisions (single, double, extended). The FPU always returns a 80-bit extended which is stored in a double without premature truncation. The 64-bit code does precision adjustment before storing.
Meanwhile I filed an issue report (https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20925), with the focus on the inconsistent results for 32- or 64-bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**:

<strike>There is only a difference in how the compiler treats the overloaded selection.</strike>

As @Graymatter found out, the `LdExp` overload called is the `Single` type for both the 32-bit and the 64-bit compiler. The only difference is the codebase, where the 32-bit compiler is using asm code, while the 64-bit compiler has a purepascal implementation.

To fix the code to use the correct overload, explicitly define the type for the `LdExp()` first argument like this it works (64-bit):

```
program Project116;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  system.sysutils, system.math;
var
  x: double;
const
  twopm1030 : UInt64 = $0000100000000000; {2^(-1030)}
begin
  x := PDouble(@twopm1030)^;
  writeln(x);
  x := ldexp(Double(1),-515);
  writeln(x*x);
  x := ldexp(Double(1),-1030);
  writeln(x);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Outputs:

```
 8.69169475979375E-0311
 8.69169475979375E-0311
 8.69169475979375E-0311
```

---

I would say that this behaviour should be reported as a RTL bug, <strike>since the overloaded function selected in your case is the `Single` type. The resulting type is a `Double` and the compiler should definitely adapt accordingly.</strike> 
since the 32-bit and the 64-bit compiler should produce the same result.

---

**Note**, the `Double(1)` typecast for floating point types, was introduced in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. For solutions in prevoius versions, see [What is first version of Delphi which allows typecasts like double(10)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51600445/576719).

Comment: Thank you. I found out for myself that ldexp is the culprit when printing x after 
`x := ldexp(1,-515)`. This is  at least inconsistent compared with 32-bit and independent of `{$EXCESSPRECISION ON/OFF}`. I will file an issue-report.

Comment: It's not a compiler bug. The compiler doesn't take the return value into account when deciding which overload to use. This is an issue with the Ldexp implementation giving different results when compiled with Win32 and Win64 because their implementations are different. Win32 uses assembler and Win64 uses pascal code.

Comment: Not a compiler bug.

Comment: @Graymatter, thanks. In the 32-bit compiler, the return value is in the floating point register, which preserves the accuray for the double, while the 64-bit compiler only operates in single precision on the XMM registers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it is a bug in the sense that the 64 bit compiler produces different result than the 32 bit compiler for the same operation. I agree that there is nothing wrong with the purepascal code, and it works in the 32 bit mode only by cpu architecture quirks and calling convention. Pity though, that overloading rules are not better documented.

Comment: It's the rtl rather than the compiler

Comment: It is not uncommon that there are slight differences between 32 and 64 bit. 32 bit may use an Extended as intermediate (either explicitly in code or implictly in the FPU), while 64 bit can‘t. This happens in other languages too.

Comment: It's can't be a compiler bug. As David said, the issue is with the RTL. If I write some code that behaves differently in Win32 and Win64 then does that mean I have broken the compiler or that there is a problem with my code? The compiler is producing different code because there is different code being compiled in both cases. If the compiler was producing different code for the same pascal source then that might be a different matter but that isn't happening here.

Comment: @Graymatter, yes that was an oversight from my side. I don't think the error will be corrected, though. The calling convention in 32 bit plus the habit to leave the FPU return register untruncated, is not likely to change. And 64-bit code is correct.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that `Ldexp(single)` is returning different results depending on whether the ASM code is being called or whether the pascal code is called. In both cases, the compiler is calling the Single version of the overload because the type isn't specified in the call.

Your pascal code which is executed in the Win64 scenario tries to deal with the exponent less than -126 but the method is still not able to correctly calculate the result because single numbers are limited to an 8 bit exponent. The assembler seems to get around this but I didn't look into it in much detail as to why that's the case.

```
function Ldexp(const X: Single; const P: Integer): Single;
  { Result := X * (2^P) }
{$IFNDEF X86ASM}
var
  T: Single;
  I: Integer;
const
  MaxExp =  127;
  MinExp = -126;
  FractionOfOne = $00800000;
begin
  T := X;
  Result := X;
  case T.SpecialType of
    fsDenormal,
    fsNDenormal,
    fsPositive,
    fsNegative:
      begin
        FClearExcept;
        I := P;
        if I > MaxExp then 
        begin
          T.BuildUp(False, FractionOfOne, MaxExp);
          Result := Result * T;
          I := I - MaxExp;
          if I > MaxExp then I := MaxExp;
        end
        else if I < MinExp then
        begin
          T.BuildUp(False, FractionOfOne, MinExp);
          Result := Result * T;
          I := I - MinExp;
          if I < MinExp then I := MinExp;
        end;
        if I <> 0 then
        begin
          T.BuildUp(False, FractionOfOne, I);
          Result := Result * T;
        end;
        FCheckExcept;
      end;
//    fsZero,
//    fsNZero,
//    fsInf,
//    fsNInf,
//    fsNaN:
  else
    ;
  end;
end;
{$ELSE X86ASM}
{$IF     defined(CPUX86) and defined(IOS)} // iOS/Simulator
...
{$ELSE} 
asm // StackAlignSafe
        PUSH    EAX
        FILD    dword ptr [ESP]
        FLD     X
        FSCALE
        POP     EAX
        FSTP    ST(1)
        FWAIT
end;
{$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF X86ASM}
```

As LU RD suggested, you can get around the problem by forcing the methods to call the Double overload. There is a bug but that bug is that the ASM code doesn't match the pascal code in `Ldexp(const X: Single; const P: Integer)`, not that a different overload is being called.