# What is first version of Delphi which allows typecasts like double(10)

Tags: delphi, casting

Delphi **Tokyo 64-bit** will compute some math functions using single precision, if called with integers constants, e.g.

```
{$apptype console}
uses
  system.math;
var
  d: double;
begin
  d := 10;
  writeln(log2(10):20:16, log2(10.0):20:16,log2(d):20:16);
end.
```

will print `3.3219280242919923  3.3219280948873626  3.3219280948873626`.

I was told in [Delphi Tokyo 64-bit flushes denormal numbers to zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445586/delphi-tokyo-64-bit-flushes-denormal-numbers-to-zero#51446947), that I should use the typecast `double(10)` to work around this feature. The problem is that, from the Delphi versions available to me, only Tokyo allows this typecast (IMO, even though the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/E2089_Invalid_typecast_%28Delphi%29) seems to forbid it, saying only a variant is allowed to be casted to a real type).

I know that XE4 (VER250) gives the error `Error: E2089 Invalid typecast` for `double(10)`, but I have no information about VER260 .. VER310.

> So which is the first Delphi version which allows the typecast `double(10)`?

Comment: What about double(10.0) like in the olden Pascal days?

Comment: @dummzeuch: What do you mean with "What..in olden Pascal days"? All Turbo Pascal and Delphi versions before Tokyo give  error messages for double(10.0). Note that calling with 10.0 works OK.

Comment: @dummzeuch, only possible in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. And does not work in TP.

Comment: @gammatester: Not *all* TP and Delphi versions. I can distinctly remember that this cast was forbidden one fine day and was allowed before. I think it was around the D2 or D3 days.

Comment: @rudy-velthuis: I have just tested it. Your remembrance is incorrect.

Comment: @gammatester: no, it isn't. It may have been a different version, or even TP, but it was allowed once. I am very sure of that. I even remember what reason was given to forbid it (see above) and that not everyone was happy with that decision. And when it was allowed, it did **not** do a conversion, it merely re-interpreted the bits. I don't know what you tested.

Comment: @rudy-velthuis: I have tested `writeln(double(10.0))` and **all** version TP4 ... XE4 give error messages!
(Interestingly BP7 and Delphi1 say 'variable expected', all others 'invalid type cast').
Prove your claim and give the version which accepts the construct.

Comment: I **know** that this behaviour was changed. I just don't know when. I don't have all versions installed and even if I had, the 16 bit products don't run here anymore. Oh, and it is @RudyVelthuis, not at rudy-velthuis.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: You **think**, you know. But you cannot prove it. Period.
(I did not test if for TP1..TP3, I do not even remember if these compilers even support double and not only 48-bit real). To run the 16-bit tests make up a VM with a non-64-bit Windows/MSDOS. Sorry about `@rudy-velthuis`, you should remove the space in your user name because
Stackoverflow links you to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/95954/rudy-velthuis`, and I always use these links to avoid other problems with character sets, special characters. etc

Comment: @gammatester: No, I don't just think I know, I do know. I was involved then. I just don't know when exactly that was. I do still know the reasons why it was introduced. And if you simply type at and r you get a hint about my name. Just use that (click on it).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: "at and r" what do you mean with this? (This reminds me of our old discussions in the delphi news groups more then 10 years ago, with the concluding statements "Let's agree that we disagree")

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, Turbo Pascal 3 was the first compiler that supported 8087 math operations. You can download it [Antique Software: Turbo Pascal v3.02](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20792) and try. I have not tested the Delphi .net versions, or the beta versions.

Comment: @gammatester: type `@r` and you will get a hint suggesting my name. If I type `@g` I get a hint with `gammatester`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: OK, it works, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XE7 fails.
XE8 fails.
...
Fails in Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

So it seems it was introduced in 10.2 Tokyo.

---

In previous versions from (XE4) you can use the integer helper methods in [SysUtils](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TIntegerHelper):

```
10.ToDouble
```

---

In versions before that, use [variant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.VarAsType) conversions:

```
VarAsType(10,varDouble)
```

---

A function that would work in all versions :

```
function DoubleVal( x : Double) : Double; inline;
begin
  Result := x;
end;
```

Comment: Why not simply use `10.0` instead of casting an integer `10` to `double`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, that would work (as exemplified in the question). The problem arised (in the linked question by the OP), when there were overloaded procedures that would return different results depending on the float type. The compiler always selects the single type, but the correct result would only be given with a double.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to cast at all. But indeed, this cast works in Tokyo 10.2.3. It didn't work in all previous versions. Casts to and from floating point types were made impossible, in order not to confuse people coming from C or C++, who expected such a cast to perfom a conversion. In Tokyo 10.2.3, it is a conversion indeed. This is indeed new.